# See / Have seen

Tags: tense

Here's a sentence that I get mixed up.

> 1. It's as if we were all friends that have know each other for a long time even though it is the first time that I see them.
> 2. It's as if we were all friends that have know each other for a long time even though it is the first time that I've seen them.

I think both are possible, but which one is the best?

Answer (score 3):

Neither example is correct.

- You need to be consistent about the tense of the frame story.
- If the frame story is present tense, you need "we are", "have known", "it is", and "I've".
- If the frame story is past tense, you need "we were", "had known", "it was", and "I'd".
- Most authors would put a comma after "known each other for a long time".

If these problems were fixed, #2 would be correct.

To my (American) ear, the following re-write sounds more natural:

> It's as if we were all friends that had known each other for a long time, even though it was the first time we'd met.

Comment: One extra comment: I'd use the present test if everyone was still together (say, seated around the table): _It's as if we are all friends who have known each other for a long time, even though this is the first time we've met._). If I were telling someone else about the event the next day, though, I'd word it the way you did (although I might start with _It was as if_ instead of _It's as if_).